# Reading strings instead of characters from a stream

Tags: java

I have a `ArrayList` class and trying to save it to a file.  I'm writing a little test method to save string to a file, then load them.

I found a method in the `FileWriter` class to write a string.  I could not find any methods in the `FileReader` to read in strings.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What types of objects are you storing in your ArrayList, and what do you want your file representation to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to store an `ArrayList` in a file is with [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(yourfile));
oos.writeObject(list);
```

To recover the arraylist you use [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html):

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourfile));
ArrayList list = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
```

The serialization format of these classes makes sure that you can safely store strings with any classes of characters without fear of breaking the output. Line-based storage, such as when using `BufferedReader.readLine` doesn't allow you to recover strings with embedded line breaks.

Comment: Ahhh so easy, thank you looks like I was barking up the wrong tree. -Ted

Comment: I CANNOT GET BYOUR SAMPLE CODE TO WORK: to work, on the line oos.write( cGlobals.conFav);, I get a error saying "is not applicable for type ArrayList"

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `writeObject` and `readObject`, not `write` and `read`. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BufferedReader` with method `readLine()`